# Find all connections in a specified component (simple, disconnected, undirected graph)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

I have the following simple, disconnected, undirected graph:

```
G1 = (V1, E1)  
V1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'x', 'y', 'z'}  
E1 = {
        {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'},  
        {'d', 'e'}, {'d', 'f'},  
        {'k', 'l'},  
        {'x', 'y'}, {'x', 'z'}
     }
```

I store it in this way:

```java
private final Map<String, List<String>> graph = Map.of(
    "a", List.of("b", "c"),
    "d", List.of("e", "f"),
    "k", List.of("l"),
    "x", List.of("y", "z"));
```

I need to implement the following method:

```java
public void apply(String connectFrom, List<String> connectTos)
```

If we call it, it should apply the new connection(s) and output every connection from the connected component in which `from` (in this example: 'a') is:

```java
apply("a", List.of("d", "k"));
```

The output should be this:

```
['a - b','a - c','a - d','a - e','a - f','a - k','a - l','b - a','b - c','b - d','b - e','b - f','b - k','b - l','c - a','c - b','c - d','c - e','c - f','c - k','c - l','d - a','d - b','d - c','d - e','d - f','d - k','d - l','e - a','e - b','e - c','e - d','e - f','e - k','e - l','f - a','f - b','f - c','f - d','f - e','f - k','f - l','k - a','k - b','k - c','k - d','k - e','k - f','k - l','l - a','l - b','l - c','l - d','l - e','l - f','l - k']
```

In this example the output contains every connection of the graph, excluded:

```
['x - y', 'x - z', 'y - x', 'y - z', 'z - x', 'z - y']
```

Because `{'x', 'y'}, {'x', 'z'}` forms a separate component:

```
G1 = (V1, E1)  
V1 = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'k', 'l', 'x', 'y', 'z'}  
E1 = {
        {'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'd'}, {'a', 'k'},  
        {'d', 'e'}, {'d', 'f'},  
        {'k', 'l'},  
        {'x', 'y'}, {'x', 'z'}
     }
```

Comment: What do you expect `apply` to do ? find a connection between a node to a list of others ? If so use [Breadth First Search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/) If you expect `apply` to find all connections use [Depth First Search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/)

Comment: can i get the above output using BFS or DFS?

Comment: Please read what BFS and DFS are used for and how. For more help post a graphic presentation of the tree and explain the output. (Hint add @c0der to the comment to address it to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/hu-zza/3e865581c928949ff811b82910ff28b6) and a [Replit snippet](https://replit.com/@huzz4/All-connections-in-component-simple-disconn-undir-graph) about my idea.

In my solution I used [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) which is quite expensive first...
But very helpful and also cheap to maintain.
Cheap... Especially without `updateComponentMapping`

These are my static helpers from the bottom of my `Graph<T>` class:

```java
//...
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Set<T> getNodeSet(Map<T, List<T>> graph) {
        Set<T> nodeSet = new TreeSet<>(graph.keySet());
        nodeSet.addAll(
            graph.values().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

        return nodeSet;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int[][] getAdjacencyMatrix(Map<T, List<T>> graph) {
        return getAdjacencyMatrix(graph, getNodeSet(graph));
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int[][] getAdjacencyMatrix(Map<T, List<T>> graph, Set<T> nodes) {
        List<T> nodeList = new ArrayList<>(nodes);
        int[][] matrix = new int[nodeList.size()][nodeList.size()];

        graph.forEach(
            (from, toList) ->
                toList.forEach(
                    to -> setAdjacency(matrix, nodeList.indexOf(from), nodeList.indexOf(to), 1)));

        return matrix;
    }

    private static void setAdjacency(int[][] matrix, int from, int to, int value) {
        matrix[from][to] = value;
        matrix[to][from] = value;
    }
}
```

Based on the static helper methods, I build a `Graph<T>` object:

```java
public static class Graph<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private final List<T> nodeList;
    private final int[][] adjacencyMatrix;
    private final int[] componentMapping;

    public Graph(Map<T, List<T>> graph) {
        var nodeSet = getNodeSet(graph);
        nodeList = new ArrayList<>(nodeSet);
        adjacencyMatrix = getAdjacencyMatrix(graph, nodeSet);
        componentMapping = new int[nodeList.size()];
        updateComponentMapping();
    }

// ...
```

Where I populate `componentMapping` with IDs to mark connected components:

```java
//...

    private void updateComponentMapping() {
        IntStream.range(0, componentMapping.length).forEach(
            i -> componentMapping[i] = i
        );

  
        int componentId;
        for (int i = 0; i < componentMapping.length; i++) {
            componentId = componentMapping[i];

            for (int j = i; j < componentMapping.length; j++) {

                if (adjacencyMatrix[i][j] == 1 && componentMapping[j] == j) {
                    componentMapping[j] = componentId;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//...
```

After that, printing is quite easy:

```java
//...

    public int getNodeId(T node) {
        int index = nodeList.indexOf(node);

        if (0 <= index && index < nodeList.size()) {
            return index;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node index is out of range.");
        }
    }

    public int getComponentId(T node) {
        return componentMapping[getNodeId(node)];
    }

    public void printAllConnections() {
        printComponentConnections(-1);
    }

    public void printComponentConnections(int componentId) {
        StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner("','", "['", "']");

        nodeList.forEach(
            from -> {
                if (getComponentId(from) == componentId || componentId < 0) {
                    nodeList.forEach(
                        to ->  {
                            if (isConnected(from, to)) {
                                result.add(String.format("%s - %s", from, to));
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }});
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(T from, T to) {
        return isConnected(getNodeId(from), getNodeId(to));
    }

    public boolean isConnected(int indexFrom, int indexTo) {
        return indexFrom == indexTo
            ? adjacencyMatrix[indexFrom][indexTo] == 1
            : componentMapping[indexFrom] == componentMapping[indexTo];
    }

//...
```

But we need new connections also, so there are `addConnection` and its helpers:

```java
//...
    public void addConnections(T from, List<T> to) {
        int fromIndex = getNodeId(from);
        to.forEach(node -> connect(fromIndex, getNodeId(node)));
        updateComponentMapping();
    }

    private void connect(int from, int to) {
        set(from, to, 1);
    }

    private void disconnect(int from, int to) {
        set(from, to, 0);
    }

    private void set(int from, int to, int value) {
        setAdjacency(adjacencyMatrix, from, to, value);
    }
//...
```

And finally...

```java
private static final Map<String, List<String>> graphMap =
    Map.of(
        "a", List.of("b", "c"),
        "d", List.of("e", "f"),
        "k", List.of("l"),
        "x", List.of("y", "z"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var graph = new Graph<>(graphMap);
    graph.addConnections("a", List.of("d", "k"));

    int componentId = graph.getComponentId("a");
    graph.printComponentConnections(componentId);
    //graph.printAllConnections();
}
```

---

I'm new to the Big O notation, but I think:

- Building the adjacency matrix first time: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- Add a new connections to adjacency matrix: O(1)
- Updating the component mapping: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- Printing connections is also: O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Thank you very much, working as expected, I may have to modify a bit as per the requirement but that should be ok, one question why did you chose adjacency matrix over adjacency list?

Comment: You're welcome. :-) I was just curious and this task was interesting. ;-)  
  
Yes, I choose a bit different methods, because the dual-function of `apply` (create connections and print) was distracting for me.  
  
About adjacency list... I'm a rookie in the world of algorithms, and the matrix was handy and clear for me. :-) This solution based on my experience, now it's time to find a better one. :-)

Comment: may be next challenge you can take it to implement the same using adjacency list :P

Comment: Or without reinventing the wheel. :-) Nice explanations and a bunch of libraries: ['Graphs in Java' on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs)